# Angular 2 http.post sending empty object

Tags: angular, express, angular2-http

Here's an authservice login, taken [from here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial):

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post(
        apiURL + '/admin/login',
        JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
            if (token) {
                // set token property
                this.token = token;

                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ email: email, token: token }));

                // return true to indicate successful login
                return true;
            } else {
                // return false to indicate failed login
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

In my component, I'm trying to subscribe like so:

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    console.log(this.model);
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.email, this.model.password)
      .subscribe(result => {
        if(result === true) {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        } else {
          this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
          this.loading = false;
        }
      });
  }
```

I've done console logs along the line to determine if the data are actually being passed, and yes. Everything checks fine.

**Except**, the sent data is just `{ }`

According to my Express console, that's the only thing coming through `req.body`. `req.headers` indicates the content types are proper, namely, `Content-Type: application/json`

I've tried sending same json request to API endpoint using POSTMan. Works fine.

Is there another trick up Angular 2's `http.post` sleeve?

What is wrong with the code above?

Comment: Ok, is the data passed or not? A bit of a contradiction here. On one hand you say data is passed, on the other you say the data is just: `{ }` :)

Comment: @AJT_82 sorry for the confusion. I mean, an empty object `{ }` is the only thing the http.post sends.

Comment: what is `this.model`?

Comment: I would expect `JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password },)` to be unhappy about the trailing comma; could you review and make sure this is a [mcve]?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to follow [this example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#update)

Comment: @suraj `this.model` is from template: `[(ngModel)]="model.email"`.

Comment: does your local storage have the value? and is the `,` a typo?

Comment: The thing is, as I said, Ive done logs along the line and the data from form to controller is intact. the only point data is lost (becomes empty) is after the `http.post` sends it.

Comment: @suraj Yes, a typo. Fixed it now.

Comment: @cartant What is there on that page I should follow? I don't see anything helpful there, honestly. Plus, I've tried appending headers using the approach on that page, and still doesn't work.

Comment: try setting the header as `content-type:application/json`

Comment: @suraj First thing I did, using example from Angularjs 2 docs (linked above by cartant. Doesn't work still

Comment: Read the linked section on sending data and note that the `post` example sets the header and *does not* call `JSON.stringify` on the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting answer here, might help someone. Thanks to @cartant for the pointers. I just had to look closer:

- I didn't need to explicitly set the headers. by default, post sends `Content-Type: application/json`
- I **DID NOT** have to stringify the data to send.

  ```
  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  // this is optional
  // let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  // let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.http.post(
      apiURL + '/admin/login',
      { email: email, password: password },
      // options
      )
      .map((response: Response) => {
          // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
          let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
          if (token) {
              // set token property
              this.token = token;

              // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
              localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ email: email, token: token }));

              // return true to indicate successful login
              return true;
          } else {
              // return false to indicate failed login
              return false;
          }
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: So, what is the solution? What did you forget?

Comment: @Enrico "I DID NOT have to stringify the data to send."